# Split an ordered list into multiple lists from multiple indexes

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking to split an ordered list into multiple lists based off of the index which gets supplied from a another list.

Starting list `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

Index list `0,3,8`

Expected lists of lists

`1,2,3`

`4,5,6,7`

`8,9,10`

Index List will always start with an index of 0. The expected list will contains all items from the starting list until Index List + 1, and so forth.

An index list of `0,2,8` would result in `1,2` `3,4,5,6,7,8` `9,10`

I've tried using GetRange and keeping track of where the next index started, then using the difference to add to a list however the amount of items being added to the expected list isn't correct.

Comment: What are rules of the split? For example index list `3,5` should result in what split?

Comment: Do you want idex list to start from 1? So Index in index list is arrayIndex + 1?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, we are starting from index 0. I've updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

```
   var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
   var indexList = new List<int> { 0, 2, 8 };
    
   // using zip for pairwise selection we can calculate lengths of each segment
   var listOfLists = indexList.Zip(indexList.Skip(1).Append(list.Count))
        .Select(i => list.GetRange(i.First, i.Second - i.First))
        .ToList();
```